# Dart Editor not launching referenced project

Tags: dart, dart-editor

In project a's pubspec, I have this code to import stuff from project b:

```
dependencies:
  project_b:
    path: /home/vilix/Program Files/Dart/workspace/project_b
```

project_b is a library and so everything is in a lib forlder. After saving pubspec from project_a, Pub Get starts working and get's all the dependencies (even devendencies needed for project_b) to project_a. After I try launching it, nothing really happens (only two lines in the console about starting pub serve and loading source assets) and after about 30 seconds the console says that there is exhausted heap space. In interval of about 5 seconds it tries to allocate more and more. After 96 bytes a warning dialog pops out saying: `Could not start pub serve or connect to pub`

Console output:

```
--- 9:06:37 PM Starting pub serve : project_a ---
Loading source assets...
Exhausted heap space, trying to allocate 48 bytes.
Exhausted heap space, trying to allocate 64 bytes.
Exhausted heap space, trying to allocate 80 bytes.
Exhausted heap space, trying to allocate 96 bytes.
Unhandled exception:
Out of memory
```

Please note that I am not even using any of those packages, just having it in pubspec.yaml file and in packages folder of project_a.

pubspec.yaml of project_a

```
name: sample
description: A sample web application
dependencies:
  project_b:
    path: /home/vilix/Program Files/Dart/workspace/project_b
```

pubspec.yaml of project_b

```
name: project_b
version: 0.0.1+11
author: name + email
description: description
homepage: homepage
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.6.0'
dependencies:
  browser: '>=0.10.0+2 <0.11.0'
  crypto: '>=0.9.0 <1.0.0'
```

Comment: Can you please post the pubspec.yaml of `project_a` and `project_b`. ... and `project_b` is a package not a library. A library is a *.dart file with a library statement at the top.

Comment: I updated the anwser, but I've tried adding some html file to project_b and launching it which resulted in the same error. The problem must be in project_b then.

Comment: Anyway, I think that I should change the name of this problem to "How to reference a project which has all it's files in lib/ folder in another folder in Dart Editor"

Comment: Uploading it to pub and then using it in my project works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem if one of my packages has a symbolic link to packages.

Apparently pub goes into an endless loop.

I have opened a bug report:
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21031

Might not be your problem.

Comment: That was my problem exactly. I spent 4 hours searching for the problem and it was just a symbolic link inside one of my packages that caused the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds very similar to this issue http://dartbug.com/21006 or http://dartbug.com/19659.